# how to pass functions to div of buttons and make button with one of functions React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have App file where i have function to filter list and i every section of the page on components on components. So i want to pass showActive, showAll and other functions to TaskControl to Button and assign to onClick. Problem is I cant pass multiple functions to Button and assign to each button.

```
App (){
const showActive = () => {
    const temp = todos.filter(todo => todo.isComplete == false)
    setNewCopy([...temp])

    console.log(temp)
  }

  const showAll = () => { 
    setNewCopy([...todos])
  }
return (
    <div className='page' >
      <div className="container">
        <Tasks tasks={todosCopy} onDelete={onDelete} onComplete={onComplete}/>
        <TaskControl tasks={todos} showActive={showActive} showAll={ showAll} />
        
        <p className='hint'>Drag and drop to reorder list</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  )
}
```

TaskControl file

```
const TaskControl = ({ tasks, showActive, showAll}) => {

    return (
            <div className="task-filter">
                <Button color='task-control-filter'  text='All' showAll={ showAll}/>
                <Button color='task-control-filter' showActive={ showActive} text='Active' />
                <Button color = 'task-control-filter' text='Completed' />
            </div>

            <Button color = 'task-control-clear' text= 'Clear Completed'/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Button file

```
const Button = ({ text, color, showActive, showAll }) => {
    return (
        <button className={`btn ${color}`} onClick={() => {
            showActive()
            showAll()
        }}> 
            {text}
        </button>
    )
}
```

I'm thinking to add id to each Button, but i don't know how use in inside Button file.

Comment: Just have one filter function but also a `boolean` state `showAll`. If that is true you show all, if not, you only show the filtered ones. No need to pass multiple functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to do any conditional rendering as suggested by aubrey1217. The answer is to pass a function as an `onClick` into your button component, and use that.

The parent component (`TaskControl`) will be in charge of deciding which function to pass (because presumably, the parent component knows what each button should do).

So
`TaskControl` is:

```
const TaskControl = ({ tasks, showActive, showAll}) => {

    return (
            <div className="task-filter">
                <Button color='task-control-filter'  text='All' onClick={ showAll}/>
                <Button color='task-control-filter' onClick={ showActive} text='Active' />
                <Button color = 'task-control-filter' text='Completed' />
            </div>

            <Button color = 'task-control-clear' text= 'Clear Completed'/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And `Button`:

```
const Button = ({ text, color, onClick }) => {
    return (
        <button className={`btn ${color}`} onClick={onClick}> 
            {text}
        </button>
    )
}
```

Much simpler and easy to read! Now the button will just call whatever function was passed to it. If you need to add a new button with a new function, then you can just specify a new onClick.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use text to help you to figure it out which button is.

```
const onClick = (text) =>{
  if(text === 'Active'){
   showActive()
  }else if(text === 'All'){
   showAll()
  }
}
const Button = ({ text, color, showActive, showAll }) => {
    return (
        <button className={`btn ${color}`} onClick={() => onClick(text)}> 
            {text}
        </button>
    )
}
```